# Сообщения при socket.recv компануются в одно

Tags: python, pyqt5, chat

Есть клиент, есть сервер(чат). Сообщения берутся из lineedit(pyqt5). Но если например написать подряд(спамом) слово "привет" 3 раза, у другого клиента оно выпишется не как 3 отдельных сообщения "привет", а как одно сообщения в котором написано "приветприветпривет". Как это исправить?
Клиент:

```
import socket
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from des import *
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QShortcut, QLabel, QApplication, QHBoxLayout
from datetime import datetime
class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send_message)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.connect_server)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.switchmode)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.ui.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)  # click on <Enter>
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)
        self.ui.smile_1.clicked.connect(self.smile1)
        self.ui.smile_2.clicked.connect(self.smile2)
        self.ui.smile_3.clicked.connect(self.smile3)
        self.ui.smile_4.clicked.connect(self.smile4)
        self.ui.smile_5.clicked.connect(self.smile5)
        self.ui.smile_6.clicked.connect(self.smile6)
        self.ui.smile_7.clicked.connect(self.smile7)
        self.ui.smile_8.clicked.connect(self.smile8)
        self.ui.smile_9.clicked.connect(self.smile9)
        
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши по форме
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Если нажата левая кнопка мыши
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # Получаем координаты окна относительно экрана
            x_main = self.geometry().x()
            y_main = self.geometry().y()
            # Получаем координаты курсора относительно окна нашей программы
            cursor_x = QtGui.QCursor.pos().x()
            cursor_y = QtGui.QCursor.pos().y()
            # Проверяем условием позицию курсора на нужной области программы(у нас это фрейм) 
            # Если всё ок - перемещаем
            # Иначе игнорируем
            if x_main <= cursor_x <= x_main + self.geometry().width():
                if y_main <= cursor_y <= y_main + self.ui.frame_2.geometry().height():
                    self.old_pos = event.pos()
                else:
                    self.old_pos = None
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # Вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # Вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.client.send(b'exit')
            self.client.close()
        except:
            pass        
    def smile1(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_1.text())
    def smile2(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_2.text())
    def smile3(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_3.text())
    def smile4(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_4.text())
    def smile5(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_5.text())
    def smile6(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_6.text())
    def smile7(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_7.text())
    def smile8(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_8.text())
    def smile9(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_9.text())

    def connect_server(self):   
            
                try:
                    if self.ui.pushButton_5.text() == 'Подключиться!':
                        self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Отключиться!")
                        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/disconnect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                        self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
                        
                        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        self.mainThread = chat(self.client)
                        self.mainThread.mysignal.connect(self.check_message)
                        self.ip = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
                        self.port = int(self.ui.lineEdit_3.text())
                        self.nick = self.ui.lineEdit_5.text()
                        self.client.connect((self.ip, self.port))
                        self.mainThread.start()
                        
                        self.client.send(self.nick.encode('utf-8'))
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                            
                        
                    elif self.ui.pushButton_5.text() == 'Отключиться!':
                        try:    
                            self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
                            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                            self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
                    
                            self.client.send(b'exit')
                            self.client.close()

                            self.ui.listWidget.clear()
                            msg = QMessageBox()
                            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
                            msg.setText(f"Успешное отключение от сервера {self.ip}:{self.port}")
                            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                            x = msg.exec_()
                        except:
                            pass
                except:
                    self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
                    msg = QMessageBox()
                    msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
                    msg.setText(f"Не удалось подключиться к серверу!")
                    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                    x = msg.exec_()
                    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                    self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)  
    def switch_smile_theme_light(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
    def switch_smile_theme_dark(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
    def switch_smile_theme_neon(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")     
    def switchmode(self):
        #светлый
        if self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Светлый режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Неоновый режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/neon_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.switch_smile_theme_light()
            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#b8b8b8; border-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #a3a3a3; border-radius: 7px"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet(
            "color: black;"
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.listWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
        #Неоновый
        elif self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Неоновый режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Темный режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/dark.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.switch_smile_theme_neon()
            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 60, 147, 255), stop:1 rgba(126, 0, 172, 255)); \nborder-radius:7px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); border-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet('color: #fff; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);')
            self.ui.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{\nbackground:rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:rgb(154, 0, 185);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}'
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{\nborder-radius: 8px;\ncolor: white;\nbackground-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground-color:rgb(199, 0, 0);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;;\ncolor: white;\nbackground:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n}')
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.listWidget.setStyleSheet("color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
        #темный
        elif self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Темный режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Светлый режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/light.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")

            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#1a1a1a; border-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background:rgb(44, 44, 44); border-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.listWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.switch_smile_theme_dark()
    
    def check_message(self, value):
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if 'Пользователь' in value:
            
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
            
            size = QtCore.QSize(45, 45)
            self.ui.listWidget.setIconSize(size)
            
            item.setText(f'[{self.current_time}] {value}')
            self.ui.listWidget.addItem(item)
            print(value)
        else:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            
            size = QtCore.QSize(45, 45)
            nick = value.partition(':')[0]
            message = value.partition(':')[2]
            item.setText(f'[{self.current_time}] {nick}:\n{message} ')
            self.ui.listWidget.setIconSize(size)
            self.ui.listWidget.addItem(item)
            print(value)
        if  item.text() == "Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате! \n":
            self.ui.listWidget.clear()
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
            self.client.send(b'exit')
            self.client.close()
            
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            msg.setText(f"Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            x = msg.exec_()
        elif item.text() == f'[{self.current_time}] Пользователь <{self.nick}> присоединился к общению!':
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
            msg.setText(f"Вы успешно присоединились к серверу {self.ip}:{self.port}!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            x = msg.exec_()
            
                        
    def send_message(self):
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if len(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()) > 0:
            message = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
            self.client.send(f'{message}'.encode('utf-8'))
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
            print(message)
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            item.setText(f'[{self.current_time}] {self.nick}(Вы):\n{message}')
            self.ui.listWidget.addItem(item)
            
class chat(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    mysignal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,server_socket, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.server_socket = server_socket
        self.message = None
        self.Nick = None
        
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.message = self.server_socket.recv(7168)
                self.decoded_message = self.message.decode('utf-8')
                self.mysignal.emit(f'{self.decoded_message}')
                
        except:
            return  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = gui()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Сервер:

```
import time
import socket
import base64
import threading
from datetime import datetime

class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.all_client = []
        self.all_nicks = []
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # Запускаем прослушивание соединений
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.server.listen(0)
        threading.Thread(target=self.connect_handler).start()
        print('Сервер готов к принятию подключений!')
    def connect_handler(self):
        while True:
            client, self.address = self.server.accept()
            user_nick = client.recv(7168)
            decoded_usernick = user_nick.decode('utf-8')
            if client not in self.all_client: 
                    if decoded_usernick not in self.all_nicks:   
                        self.all_client.append(client)
                        self.all_nicks.append(decoded_usernick)
                        threading.Thread(target=self.message_handler, args=(client, decoded_usernick, )).start()
                        for client in self.all_client:
                            client.send(f'Пользователь <{decoded_usernick}> присоединился к общению!'.encode('utf-8'))
                        
                        
                    else:
                        client.send('Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате! \n'.encode('utf-8'))
            time.sleep(2)                
    def message_handler(self, client_socket, decoded_usernick):
        while True: 
            message = client_socket.recv(7168)
            if message == b'exit':
                self.all_client.remove(client_socket)
                self.all_nicks.remove(decoded_usernick)
                for client in self.all_client:
                        client.send(f'Пользователь <{decoded_usernick}> отсоединился от чата!'.encode('utf-8'))
                break
            for client in self.all_client:
                if client != client_socket:
                    client.send(decoded_usernick.encode('utf-8') + ':'.encode('utf-8') + message)
            time.sleep(2)
myserver = Server('0.0.0.0', 1234)
```

Comment: когда Вы отправляете сообщения через сокет с помощью send/recv никто не записывает размер самого сообщения и принимающая или передающая сторона могут их склеить или разбить поудобнее. Вам только гарантируется последовательность байт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было убрать time.sleep(2) у message_handler